# How to get an element that rendered after document ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have code like this:

```
// HTML
<div id="filter-option"></div>

//Javascript
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "Some Url",
    data: {Some: "Data"}
}).done(funtion(msg){
    var result = JSON.parse(msg);
    renderFilterOption(result) // Some function to render elements to #filter-option
})

$("#myID").on('click', '.myClass', function(){
    var active = $("#ElementInFilterOption").attr("id");
    console.log(active);
})
```

When I console log `active` that contain and id of element that rendered after document ready, it return `undefined`. How to fix it?

Comment: Yes, because the element does not exist yet. You should do yourself a favor and learn the basics of asynchronous programming in Javascript, it will make your life a lot easier once you know how to work with callbacks and promises.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```js
// HTML
<div id="filter-option"></div>

//Javascript
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "Some Url",
    data: {Some: "Data"}
}).done(funtion(msg){
    var result = JSON.parse(msg);
    renderFilterOption(result) // Some function to render elements to #filter-option

    $("#myID").on('click', '.myClass', function(){
        var active = $("#ElementInFilterOption").attr("id");
        console.log(active);
    })
})
```

By moving the click event handler inside the `done()` function, you will be adding the event handler to that element after it has been added to the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

You should do this instead:

```js
// Post request
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "Some Url",
    data: {Some: "Data"}
}).done(funtion(msg){
    var result = JSON.parse(msg);
    renderFilterOption(result)
    $("#myID").on('click', '.myClass', function(){
        var active = $("#ElementInFilterOption").attr("id");
        console.log(active);
    })
})
```

`$.ajax` is a promise and they're asynchronous. What you did is synchronous. `done()` is a callback called after `$.ajax` is done. The code after `$.ajax` still proceeds even if `$.ajax` is not done yet.